# Joint entropy of sum and difference of random variables

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $X$~$U\left\{1,8 \right\}$ , $Y$~ $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  & \dots \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & \dots 
\end{pmatrix}$. I need to calculate $H(X+Y,X-Y)$. I can do it by computing probability distribution of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$, but I think, there is some other, more elegant way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Continuous uniform or discrete?

Comment: Also, $Y\sim\operatorname{Geometric}(1/2)$?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson discrete uniform, and, yes, Y ~ Geometric(1/2)

Comment: a) You need the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Presumably they are independent (but you should check the source of the question). b) Notice that $H(X+Y, X-Y) = H(X,Y)$, since given $X,Y$ you can exactly figure out $X+Y, X-Y$, and vice versa. With independence, this is further equal to $H(X) + H(Y)$, so you can just separately figure out the entropies and add them up.